# Javascript Objects in IE8

Tags: javascript, object, flot

Im having issues using flot in IE8. I am pulling in the excanvas.js file fine, but IE seems to have an issue with my object now. Here is the code that I use to try and build the bar chart

```
var uptime = [];
            var TotalUptime = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i < data.Service.length; i++){
                var UptimeValues = parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_UP) + parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_MAINT) + parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_DEGRADED);
                uptime.push([-i, UptimeValues / 14.4]);
                TotalUptime = TotalUptime + UptimeValues;
            }
            var ChartData = [
                {
                    data: uptime,
                    color: '#bfd730',
                    bars: {show: true, align:'center', barWidth:0.1, fillColor:'#bfd730'}
                },
            ];
            var options = {
                xaxis: {ticks:[[-1, 'Now']], color: '#ffffff', min: -30, max: -1},
                yaxis: {color: '#ffffff', min: 0 ,max: 100}
            };
            $.plot($("#ServiceInfoChart"), ChartData, options);
```

The response I get is 'data' is null or not an object.

I have confirmed that it is not any issues with flot itself because I put static values in there and the chart renders fine. I do not have any issues with any other browsers using the code above.

Is there something I am missing?

EDIT: Full function

I am making a request which will send back a JSON response like

```
{"Service": [{"Name":"SomeService","Status":"UP","Description":"Some Description"},{"Date":"2012-04-02","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-04-01","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-04-00","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-30","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-29","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-28","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-27","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-26","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-25","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-24","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-23","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-22","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-21","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-20","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-19","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-18","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-17","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-16","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-15","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"},{"Date":"2012-03-14","TIME_UP":"1440.00","TIME_DOWN":"0.00","TIME_MAINT":"0.00","TIME_DEGRADED":"0.00"}]}
```

This is the full function that handles it below.

```
function GoToServiceInfo(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get.php?Request=ServiceInfoFull',
        timeout: 10000,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings){
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("SessionID", SessionID);
        },
        success: function(data){
            CheckForContactInfo();
            GetSubscriptions();
            $('#' + $('#content').find(':visible').attr('id')).slideToggle('fast', function(){
                $('#ServiceInfo').slideToggle('fast');
            });
            $('#ServiceInfoTitle').html(data.Service[0].Name);
            $('#ServiceInfoDescription').html('<h1>Description</h1>' + data.Service[0].Description);
            var uptime = [];
            var TotalUptime = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i < data.Service.length; i++){
                var UptimeValues = parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_UP) + parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_MAINT) + parseFloat(data.Service[i].TIME_DEGRADED);
                uptime.push([-i, UptimeValues / 14.4]);
                TotalUptime = TotalUptime + UptimeValues;
            }
            var ChartData = [
                {
                    data: uptime,
                    color: '#bfd730',
                    bars: {show: true, align:'center', barWidth:0.1, fillColor:'#bfd730'}
                },
            ];
            var options = {
                xaxis: {ticks:[[-1, 'Now']], color: '#ffffff', min: -30, max: -1},
                yaxis: {color: '#ffffff', min: 0 ,max: 100}
            };
            $.plot($("#ServiceInfoChart"), ChartData, options);
            var TotalUptimePercent = (TotalUptime / (data.Service.length - 1)) / 14.4;
            $('#UptimePercent').html('Uptime Past 30 Days <font color="#bfd730"> ' + TotalUptimePercent.toFixed(3) + '%</font>');
        },
        error: function(x, t, m) {
            if(t==="timeout") {
                noty({text: 'Error!', type: 'error', timeout: 2500});
            } else {
                noty({text: m, type: 'error', timeout: 2500});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: IE8 should come with Developer Tools - please post here the full error you get and what line of code is causing it.

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Tue, 3 Apr 2012 07:39:37 UTC


Message: 'data' is null or not an object
Line: 310
Char: 17
Code: 0

Comment: You have this: `data.Service[i].TIME_UP` - so where `data` **should** come from? Please post more code and explain where and how you define this object.

Comment: I made the update, not sure if you could see it...

Comment: No, I don't get notification when you edit so saw it just now. This means that the response from the server is raw string, not complex object. Have `alert(data)` to see the response, and you'll have to parse it yourself. (possible with `JSON.parse` if the format is correct)

Comment: As a side note - when you have more than one user commenting you have to use `@` to notify - for example if somebody else would comment here I will be notified only if you add `@Sha` (3 characters are enough) to your comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sweet. thanks for the tip there

Comment: Sure - what about the data? Any luck with it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No I cant seem to parse the JSON string. I get Unexpected token o when trying to do JSON.parse(data) or JSON.parse(data.Response) or JSON.parse(data.Response[0]). Any ideas?

Comment: But what does it contain? How the string looks like?

Comment: @ShadowWizard its the exact same string as what you see above. I changed the name and description but thats the exact string.

Comment: `$.parseJSON` is working in your case. What you need is `if (typeof data === "string") data = $.parseJSON(data)` above the loop and it should work. [Test case with your data](http://jsfiddle.net/LrEq6/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9632/discussion-between-dvideby0-and-shadow-wizard)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it asked me to do a chat. im not very familiar with chat yet.

Comment: It's just a suggestion we don't have to move to the chat. Did you try what I suggested above?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did try but Im thinking its fine with how 'data' looks. I think the proproblem is with my 'uptime' array I create. It appears flot is looking for a object and not an array. though I thought an array was an object in JS...

Comment: if you look at the flot examples and the source code they send a value like var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]]; and when I look at my array it looks the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like there was a trailing comma in my code that IE8 didnt like. Hours later I deleted it and now everything is working!